# Using Next.JS Router Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js, next-router

First of all, I'm kinda new to Next.js, and React in general.

I have the page "Projects" and I want to redirect the user to the Product Page Details and I'm using this:

```
const openProjectDetails = () => {
  Router.push('/api/' + props.projetos.key);
}
```

And this is the code in the "/api/[key].js"

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const ProjectDetails = () => {
   const router = useRouter();
   const { key } = router.query;
   
   return (
      <div>
         {/* Display the project details */}
      </div>
   );
};

export default ProjectDetails;
```

What I'm I missing? This is the only page that gives me that error, and the error comes from:
`const router = useRouter();`

Sorry again if this is basic, but I'm new to this.

> Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

I'm expecting to pass the key value and get all project fields from db, but because of that error, it doesnt work.

Comment: can you try please to use useEffect on router. [router.query] if it would help or wouldnt let me know please

Comment: I tried and it did not work, it gives me this: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')"

Comment: then could you please try [router] in useEffect and add `if/else` where `if(router){console.log(router.query)}`

Comment: Like this?

`const ProjectDetails = () => {
   
    const router = useRouter();
    const { key } = router.query;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router){
            console.log(router.query);
        }
    }, []);

   return (
      <div>
      </div>
   );
};`

Comment: no not really. dont use `{key}=router.query` before useEffect. and also you need to pass in useEffect dependency (the array) [router].

Comment: But the error hightlights in `const router = useRouter();`
I changed to what you gived me, and the console, only appears the error

Comment: its indend strange, sorry mate i cant help you with this.

Comment: I can Share the codeSandbox link if you want

Comment: ye why not. Let me see

Comment: Why are you using the pages/api directory for serving normal pages? Can you try creating something like pages/products/[key].js and see whether you still getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use useRouter in an API page since it is a hook and can only be used in client side pages (while API pages are server side).

It doesn't seem like you understand the whole idea of API pages since they shouldn't return an HTML element but JSON and etc, this is why I would recommend to just use `/projects/[key].js` instead of API if you wish to have an HTML page and not a JSON file.

But regardless, if you want to get the value of [key] you don't even need useRouter.
Your ProjectDetails function should look like this:

```
const ProjectDetails = ({params}) => {
   
   const key = params.id
   // key now has the value of [key] in the URL
   
   return (
      <div>
         {/* Display the project details */}
      </div>
   );
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I understanded, I read the what would the API folder do, and now I created another folder like the one that you mentioned